# Heroku Login Error: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined

Tags: python-3.x, django, heroku

Olá!

Estou obtendo o seguinte erro ao tentar efetuar o login.

```
heroku login
heroku: Enter your login credentials
Email: ########@gmailTypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined 
    at new HerokuAPIError (C:/ProgramFiles/heroku/client/node_modules/@heroku-cli/command/lib/api_client.js:12:33)
    at Login.login (C:/Program Files/heroku/client/node_modules/@heroku-cli/command/lib/login.js:78:19)
```

Alguém já passou por este problema, e teria a solução?

Comment: Recebi uma dica pelo GitHub.

Um atalho para resolver o problema, por enquanto é:

Digitar seu e-mail em um editor de texto, depois copiar para minha área de transferência e colando-o rapidamente antes que o erro aparecesse. Isso me permitiu entrar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saiu uma atualização que resolve o problema.

No GitHub, o jdxcode que é membro do Heroku, informou que a última atualização (7.0.88) resolve o problema no login.

Basta apenas executar o update.

```
C:\Users\Marcio                                                                    
λ heroku update                                                                    
heroku: Updating CLI from 7.0.87-beta.5da7c01 to 7.0.87-beta.99c8869 (beta)... done
heroku: Updating CLI... done                                                       

C:\Users\Marcio                                                                    
λ heroku login                                                                     
heroku: Enter your login credentials                                               
Email: ########@gmail.com                                                        
Password: **********                                                              
Logged in as #######@gmail.com
```